# Oracle Application Express shows deleted data from oracle table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have deleted a row from Oracle

```
delete from student where gr_number = 51777;
```

In Oracle Application Express form that contain interactive report, fetching data from student it shows deleted row.  I also check by using SQL commands from Oracle Application Express and it shows deleted row again

```
select * from student where gr_number = 51777;
```

Please tell why Oracle Application Express displays deleted record from Oracle table.

I am using Oracle Application Express 18.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you didn't **COMMIT** after issuing `DELETE`.